# Create Android Studio SDK Project like Xcode Framework

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but I can't seem to find it. Coming from iOS, in Xcode, you can create a new Framework (SDK) project. In Android Studio, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that. I can create a Project, and then create a new module, Android Library. Is that the only way to do it? To do it with an accompanying "app"? I couldn't seem to find any other way.

Also a side question, is there a reason why if you name a project `my-project`, it creates packages as com.mycompany.my_project. Is there any way getting around that besides naming your project as MyProject?

Comment: library is the sdk. And that is the naming convention for packages in android. com.companydomain.appname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Android Library Module" is actually equivalent to Xcode framework concept.

[image: Android Library Module]

> Is that the only way to do it? To do it with an accompanying "app"? I couldn't seem to find any other way.

At the moment, yes, creating a project then creating a new library module and deleting the `app` module is the easiest way.

This link [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) tells how to rename the package name.

For how to change application ID, see here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mylibary"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Also note that, **Android Library** project does not have applicationId.